# New line `\n` not being respected when reading from SQflite result

Tags: json, flutter, widget, richtext, sqflite

I have a line break `\n` in a string that I'm reading from my sqflite row (the specific column data type is TEXT) through the bloc state, and am trying to display it within a TextSpan-

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: _state.feedback,  //this is the string
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      color: Colors.black
    )
   ),
 )
```

When doing this, it just renders onscreen as the literal `some text \n some text`, but if I hardcode the same string as the text value instead of reading from the bloc state, eg:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: "some text \n some text"
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      color: Colors.black
    )
   ),
 )
```

I've tried with just a plain `Text(_state.feedback)` widget as well, and I get the exact same behaviour.. line break works correctly when I hard-code the text value, but won't break when reading the string from the column value.

Has anyone else experienced this or can see something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this:

```
text: "${_state.feedback}",
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work.

```
text: _state.feedback.replaceAll(r'\n', '\n'),
```

Comment: it does and it's what I ended up doing last year.. however I feel that it's more of a hacky workaround rather than a fix, and I'd still like to know why it's necessary in the first place.